# Influence of a Capacitance Matrix of a voltage measurment

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current, capacitance, voltage

I am having a problem in understanding how in a multiconductor system the Capacitance Matrix influences the measure of voltage between two electrodes.

In the case that interest me we have 4 electrodes, 2 emitting ones and 2 receiving ones. We transmit a known sinusoidal current into the the emitting electrodes and we measure a voltage on the receiving ones.

We are looking for the phase and amplitude difference between the current emitted and the measured voltage.

It is my understanding that the measured voltage is influenced by any conductor present in the medium close-by, therefore we have to determine the Capacitance Matrix to obtain the real voltage measured.

$$
V_{real} = V_{measured} * C_{ij}
$$

What I don't understand is the relation between the measured voltage ($V_{measured}$), the capacitance matrix ($C_{ij}$) and the real voltage ($V_{real}$).

If any of you could help understand this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem :

The equations can be written :

$$
I = V  \times  C_{ij} \times i\omega
$$

Where $I$ is the vector of known currents going threw the electrodes, $V$ the potential of the electrodes and $\omega$ the rotational frequency of the current.

In this case the potential of the transmitting electrodes is known and the current of the receiving electrodes is equal to 0. We can therefore find a system of equations that will allow us to derive the potential of the receiving electrodes.